# cannot find library with -L/lib/path

Tags: c

New to C, and try to make my own first library. However gcc says library not found.
with -L/lib/path, it should be ok, but it's not.

FYI, i use Mac os x.

```
~/c$make
gcc -c -o obj/hellomake.o src/hellomake.c -I./include
gcc -c -o obj/hellofunc.o src/hellofunc.c -I./include
gcc -o hellomake obj/hellomake.o obj/hellofunc.o -I./include -L./lib -lm -llibfunc
ld: library not found for -llibfunc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hellomake] Error 1

~/c$ls ./lib
README.txt libfunc.a  libfunc1.c libfunc1.o libfunc2.c libfunc2.o
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-l` argument automatically prepends the `lib` part to the library name.  So the command should use `-lfunc` in place of `-llibfunc`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `lib` when linking `libfunc`. Just use `-lfunc`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-lfunc`, skip the prefix `lib.`